# Compare columns then display row on userform listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that has many records. I want to compare 12 columns.

The first column compares if the values are (< 0 and >=-30), (<-31 and >=-60), (<-61 and >=-90), (<-91 and >=-180), (<-181 and >=-365), (<-90), (<=-365) and (<=-1) then display that row on my userform listbox and also the same for the rest of the columns.

I cannot see the result on my userform listbox.

```vb
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Dim a As Long
Dim i As Integer

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 152) < 0 And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 152) >= -30 Then
        userform1.listbox1= Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Show
    elseif Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 152) < -31 And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 152) >= -60 Then
        userform1.listbox1= Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Show
    End If
.
.
.

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I believe you when you write that this code does not work. Where in your [ListBox control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/listbox-control-additem-removeitem-methods-listindex-listcount-properties-exampl) are you trying to place the result of the  method [.Rows(i).Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.show)?

Comment: Please JohnSUN, can you help me on that?

Comment: I can't help you until you figure out your desires yourself. Let's take a look at all your difficult conditions and try to understand what values ​​will correspond to the selection. <0 (part of the very first condition) and <= - 1 (the very last condition) will allow not checking everything else - the whole set of sequential checks is reduced to one simple condition *"select all rows whose value in column 152 (this is the EV column) is less than zero"*. Please, think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure might look something like this:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aRange As Range
Dim aDataToList As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer
Dim aData As Variant
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set aRange = ws.Range("EV1").CurrentRegion
    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .RowSource = vbNullString
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = -1
    End With
    aRange.AutoFilter
    aRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlAnd
    Set aDataToList = aRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(aRange.Rows.Count - 1, 12).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    aRange.AutoFilter

    UserForm1.ListBox1.List = aDataToList.Areas(1).Value2
    For i = 2 To aDataToList.Areas.Count
        aData = aDataToList.Areas(i).Value2
        For j = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
            UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem
            For k = 1 To 12
                UserForm1.ListBox1.List(UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, k - 1) = aData(j, k)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```